# Vertical centering with header and footer in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a responsive page like this:

[image: page preview]

It should could be scaled fine vertically and horizontally. It is easy to do it with tables using

`<tr height="1">..</tr>`

for the header and footer: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E88Lp/2/).

But how to do it using Bootstrap containers? (or, if it is not possible, plain CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `margin: 0 auto;` This is the HTML5 way of `align:center;`. You have to have a set width. here is an example.: http://jsfiddle.net/TgGvw/